# GAE - Development server in Eclipse doesn't update?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I'm using the Google AppEngine development server on Eclipse. My local webpage just doesn't seem to update until I do a number of restarts on the Development Server (using the Run or Debug buttons from Eclipse).

What am I doing wrong ?

The basic flow is:

- Make change to .java file...
- Save file
- Run application (development server loading log shows in console)
- Refresh web page in browser

**P.S:** The only way I can get it to work is to change the server port... and if I do that all the previous servers still show at their respective ports. They never stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need to restart the server to see most code changes you'll make.  The easiest way to do this is with the yellow reload button that appears on the GAE pane - not the console, but the one that has the fancy "click here to launch" addresses.

If you do use the debug / run commands in eclipse, you will need to explicitly stop the previous run.  You can do this from the debug menu (the stop button) or from the GAE pane or from the console pane.

You won't need to change the ports after this - the reason you have to do it now is that the first instance is still running, hogging the port.  Once you stop it you'll be able to run it again on the same port... WITH your code changes! :)

Comment: Yeah... I figured it was something like that.... I finally found my way to the previous consoles and shutdown the server instances. But I still don't see the GAE pane with the yellow button... I only have a single button with the 'G' which drops down to give the New Project, Deploy to AppEngine, GWT, etc. options... do you know how to enable the GAE Pane view ?

Comment: Window > Show View > Development Mode (should have a little blue circle w/ a G)

Comment: You can also close all inactive consoles with the double-x icon in the console window, which helps find and shut down other instances.

Comment: Damn... I've got to learn to look in Show View... it will be my downfall someday... thanks for the help.