# GAE Development - Development Environment Setup (HotSwap)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, hotswap

I'm quite new to develop on GAE. Need just sort out few questions about setting up development.

I'm currently using **Eclipse 3.7.x**, **Google Suite Plugin 2.5.2 r37**

Related links I found:

- http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1787
- [GAE - Development server in Eclipse doesn't update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150406/gae-development-server-in-eclipse-doesnt-update)
- http://code.google.com/p/gae-wtp-plugin/

I came from standard LAMP development environment. Changes are propagated immediately to development server (usually localhost) and I can control deployment of application to production server through DCVS/SVN and attached handlers updating remote codebase.

I'd expect Google Plugin allowing us to do the same. Necessary functions I (probably) need:

- **On-Save handler to recompile and update development code**
- **Production like development environment (for testing in almost-real conditions)**
- Deployment to production environment

The last one is simply using DCVS/SVN to tag code and save the trunk branch, and using `Google > Deploy to App Engine` option to push it to remote server.

**But how can I solve the first two requirements? Do I really need them, or is it only my hangover from web development, and development process in GAE works differently?**

If the first one is solvable through GAE WTP Plugin, can you please more elaborate on how to setup development with this plugin, as I was not able to achieve anything more, than server, which has to be restarted in the same manner as Google Plugin default GAE development server 
 does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update development code pretty quickly with the yellow reload button.  For me, with about 100 server classes, this takes 2-5 seconds.

The development environment is reasonably good - you can simulate HRD and stuff like that.  Of course, it's not actually a distributed cloud environment - we do most testing on local servers, and then have a whole test app on the cloud for a last round of simulation.  Of course, some things change when 1000 people are accessing it at once, but I don't know how to get around that.

You can find the reload button on the Development View pane:

[image: Window > Show View > Development Mode]

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I don't see such button. What UI perspective do you use?

Comment: You can add the view to any perspective - check out my edited answer w/ explanations

Comment: Thanks Riley, this really helped me out.